# {\LaTeX} symbol in groff

Tags: latex, groff

Is there a way to print the {\LaTeX} original symbol in groff?
I would like to use the typography every time the word LaTeX appears in a document made with groff.

Comment: what do you mean by "{\LaTeX} symbol"?

Comment: @jarnosz the LaTeX logo. Something like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7546/how-to-get-latex-symbol-in-document)

Answer (score 1):

You could do it the way the *pic*(1) man page from *groff* does it.

```
.ie t \{\
.  ds tx T\h'-.1667m'\v'.224m'E\v'-.224m'\h'-.125m'X
.  ds lx L\h'-0.36m'\v'-0.22v'\s-2A\s0\h'-0.15m'\v'0.22v'\*[tx]
.\}
.el \{\
.  ds tx TeX
.  ds lx LaTeX
.\}
```

What this does is define strings for TeX *and* LaTeX, using the former to build the latter.  But it also provides alternate definitions for non-typesetter devices (like terminals) so that the strings are still readable on devices that aren't capable of small horizontal and vertical motions.  (That's what the `\h` and `\v` escape sequences do.)

You interpolate strings in the *roff* language by using the `\*` escape sequence.  Here's where *pic*(1) does this.

```
To give the vbox a positive height and a depth of zero
(as used by \*[lx]'s
.IR \%graphics.sty ,
for example)
define the following macro in your document.
```

You can find the source of the above examples in *groff*'s Git repository.

https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/groff.git/tree/src/preproc/pic/pic.1.man?id=c2e894cf5b42cfdaae48f03476fee24a6103f9c9#n39

https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/groff.git/tree/src/preproc/pic/pic.1.man?id=c2e894cf5b42cfdaae48f03476fee24a6103f9c9#n413